# TYPO3: specify a plugin name

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I want to link to a page, where I have a plugin, I want to send a variable through GET and display in that page with that plugin some record.

The idea is to have an extension where I can have a plugin for listing records and another plugins for displaying a detailed view of a record. (and another to create a new record for that matter)

And I'm getting this error, but I don't know what does it mean, where should I specify a plugin? As which parameter? Because `<f:link.page>` does not have a pluginName parameter.

> There is more than one plugin that can handle this request (Extension:
> "MyExtension", Controller: "MyController", action: "new"). Please
> specify "pluginName" argument.

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.pageUid}" additionalParams="{theIdINeed: theIdINeed}">
link
</f:link.page>
```

```php
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
  'MyVendor.MyExtension',
  'ViewPlugin',
  [
      \MyVendor\MyExtension\Controller\TheController::class => 'show',
  ],
  [
      \MyVendor\MyExtension\Controller\TheController::class => '',
  ]
);
```

This is my method, seems that the error is occurring after this method.

```php
public function showAction()
{
    $model = $this->someRepository->findByUid( $_GET['theIdIneed']);
    $this->view->assign('model', $model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of general parameters (`theIdIneed`) you normally have specific parameters like `pluginname[action]`, `pluginname[controller]` and `pluginname[tablename]`.
if you have an ID with `pluginname[tablename]` most times it is obvious that you want to `show` this record with the matching controller and these parameters can be omitted.

In this way the plugin is identified.

For better readability you might map this parameter into pseudo path segments (slugs).

---

another thought (you may need to be more specific):
if you have the same plugin inserted on a page multiple times and you want these different content elements behave differently you need additional information. either stored in global variables (like ext:news which stores a list of already displayed news, so the same news is not teasered multiple times on the same page) or you give an additional parameter (uid of tt_content record) identifying the specific plugin which should respond. But you need to evaluate it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Please use <f:link.action> viewhelper. You can specify action, controller, extension and plugin. Thus there is no need for GET paramters. (I assume that you are starting from an overview or search result page and want to link to a details plugin.)

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach, I must have something else wrong. Because after defining the controller and the action on the link I was getting that my "show" action expects for a parameter and I was not getting it, and that's why I changed it to $_GET. May be the problem is that my plugin is calling by default this 'view' action? I don't know how to do it otherwise.
That looks weird for me, why I define the controller and the action on the plugin (in ext_localconf.php) and then again on the link.action?